# Is safe to store passwords in Android/iOS App own storage?

Tags: password-management, mobile

I'm creating an app that logins to a remote API that doesn't implement oauth2 or another similar mechanism, and I want to know if is *reasonably* safe to assume that password will be safe if is stored in app private storage like [Shared preferences](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) or SQLite?

Comment: Storing passwords on a non-encrypted device is just asking for trouble.

Comment: Safe against what? What is your threat model? Who's the attacker?

Comment: I'm a little confused how the local storage mechanism and the remote API framework have anything to do with each other to be able to design a secure process. "... password will be safe ..." from what? When? What conditions are you worried about?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OWASP, an org that provides guidance to app developers, has a few reference material:

1. The original Mobile Top Ten 2012 Insecure Data Storage reference -- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mobile_Top_10_2012-M1
2. The updated Mobile Top Ten 2014 Insecure Data Storage reference -- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Mobile_Top_10_2014-M2
3. An iOS Developers Cheat Sheet which makes specific suggestions about where to store what types of data, when it is required of an app's functional tasks -- https://www.owasp.org/index.php/IOS_Developer_Cheat_Sheet#Insecure_Data_Storage_.28M1.29

For Android, I might suggest using [secure-preferences](https://github.com/scottyab/secure-preferences) instead of the Shared Preferences you suggested, or perhaps [cwac-prefs](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-prefs). Check out examples of these in the book Android Security Cookbook.

On iOS, be sure to read the iOS Application Security book, which recommends [Lockbox](https://github.com/granoff/Lockbox) to store data in the Keychain, as well as methods to add and remove credentials. If you're building an iOS mobile app, this book is highly-recommended.

If you don't like or for some reason can't use Lockbox (or just want to try different options), then check out this idea from the book, Mobile Application Penetration Testing:

> Utilize the different options provided by Apple, as we learned in the
>   section Keychain data protection in Chapter 2, Snooping Around the
>   Architecture. You can also utilize one of the simple wrapper
>   PDKeyChainBindingController
>   (https://github.com/carlbrown/PDKeychainBindingsController) to secure
>   the keychain data. However, if the device is jailbroken then keychain
>   information is not secure. It is recommended to use custom encryption
>   techniques to encrypt the string that is stored in the keychain. Make
>   the best use of the keychain services API
>   (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/keychainServConcepts/01introduction/introduction.html).

The book also covers another issue related to credential storage in the Keychain:

> On June 18, 2015, a password stealing vulnerability, also known as
>   XARA (Cross Application Resource Attack), outlined for iOS and OS X
>   cracked the Keychain services on jail broken and non-jail broken
>   devices. The vulnerability is similar to the cross-site request
>   forgery attack in web applications. In spite of Apple's isolation
>   protection and its App Store's security vetting, it was possible to
>   circumvent the security controls mechanism. It clearly provided the
>   need to protect the cross-app mechanism between the operating system
>   and the app developer. Apple rolled out a security update week after
>   the XARA research. More information can be found at
>   http://www.theregister.co.uk/2015/06/17/apple_hosed_boffins_drop_0day_mac_ios_research_blitzkrieg/

and provides details on the Keychain itself, should one utilize a jailbroken device to attempt to get access to it

> Keychain in an iOS device is used to securely store sensitive
>   information such as credentials, such as usernames, passwords,
>   authentication tokens for different applications, and so on, along
>   with connectivity (Wi-Fi/VPN) credentials and so on. It is located on
>   iOS devices as an encrypted SQLite database file located at
>   /private/var/Keychains/keychain-2.db

Answer (score 1):

Answer provided is wrong, according to the Android native documentation

> In general, we recommend minimizing the frequency of asking for user credentials -- to make phishing attacks more conspicuous, and less likely to be successful. Instead use an authorization token and refresh it.
>
> Where possible, username and password should not be stored on the device. Instead, perform initial authentication using the username and password supplied by the user, and then use a short-lived, service-specific authorization token.

It is in the training docs here:

https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips#UserData